# Connect flutter to HFSQL DATABASE

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering if anyone could show us how to connect a Flutter app to HFSQL database and how to make CRUD Operations

I'm trying to get data from existing HFSQL database with flutter app

i did some researches but nothing helped me

thank you